# Redirect output of <command> --help via ccat?

Tags: zsh, pipe, colors

I can `ls --help | ccat` but I want `ls --help` print the same colored output as `ls --help | ccat`.

In short, I want all commands to be filtered through `ccat`. How may I do this in the `zsh` shell?

Comment: This feels wrong on so many levels - first off, you shouldn't use `cat` to look at text files. Second, from a quick glance I learned that `ccat` is used for syntax highlighting - but the output of `ls --help` isn't source code.

Comment: redirect to `ccat` to get text colorized. I ended up to use default `white` text instead.

Comment: Your `ls` is likely aliased to `ls --color=auto`, which turns coloring off when the output is piped. Try `ls --color=always`.

Comment: It should apply for all command like `<command> <arg1> <arg2..> | ccat`, `ls` is an example.

Comment: Where is this `ccat` command from? The only such command I can find in commonly available packages is something distributed with [`ccrypt`](http://ccrypt.sourceforge.net/), and it is _not_ used for colorising text.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this into your `.zshrc` instead:

```bsh
export HELPDIR=$MANPATH
alias -L run-help > /dev/null && unalias run-help
autoload -Uz  run-help    run-help-git  run-help-ip   run-help-openssl \
              run-help-p4 run-help-sudo run-help-svk  run-help-svn
```

Then, instead of typing `ls --help`, just type `ls` and press <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>h</kbd>. You'll get a nicely colored `man` page.

This will work on any command, even if you've already entered arguments for them.